# JButton is displaying behind image

Tags: java, image, jframe, jbutton, calculator

So hello there :), this is my fist post here.
Lets get right into it:
My problem:
I put a calculator as a background image, than added a JButton to it.
My Problem(s):

When I start the program the calculator is quickly shown, then it vanishes and the button is shown
When I resize the window, the calculator shows up and the button dissapears

How can I make this work?

Heres my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel label;


Calculator() {


    image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TStiny.png"));
    label = new JLabel(image);
    add(label);
}

public static void main (String args[]) {

    Calculator gui = new Calculator();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setTitle("Texas Instruments TI-30XIIS");
    gui.pack();
    gui.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    gui.add(panel);

    JButton button7 = new JButton();
    button7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Calculator.class.getResource("button_7.png")));
    button7.setVisible(true);
    button7.setBorderPainted(false);
    button7.setBounds(90, 445, 45, 35);
    panel.add(button7);

}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the layout and eventual position to which you want to add the component. `JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` by default.

If you want to use the default behavior, you should put a position on which to place the component:

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel label;


    Calculator() {
        image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TStiny.png"));
        label = new JLabel(image);
        add(label, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Calculator gui = new Calculator();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setTitle("Texas Instruments TI-30XIIS");
        gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        gui.add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        JButton button7 = new JButton();
        button7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Calculator.class.getResource("button_7.png")));
        button7.setVisible(true);
        button7.setBorderPainted(false);
        button7.setBounds(90, 445, 45, 35);
        panel.add(button7);

    }
}
```

Another option is to specify a layout that does not want to specify a position - such as `FlowLayout`:

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel label;


    Calculator() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TStiny.png"));
        label = new JLabel(image);
        add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Calculator gui = new Calculator();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setTitle("Texas Instruments TI-30XIIS");
        gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        gui.add(panel);

        JButton button7 = new JButton();
        button7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Calculator.class.getResource("button_7.png")));
        button7.setVisible(true);
        button7.setBorderPainted(false);
        button7.setBounds(90, 445, 45, 35);
        panel.add(button7);

    }
}
```